# Python: Getting all values of a specific key from json

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I'm using an API that returns data in JSON format like that:

```
{
    "ABC": {
        "A": {
            "X": "1",
            "Y": "2",
            "Z": "3",
        },
        "B": {
            "X": "4",
            "Y": "5",
            "Z": "6",
        },
        "C": {
            "X": "7",
            "Y": "8",
            "Z": "9",
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to get all values of a specific key in a list, in this simple example for the key `"Y"`, the list should look like this: `[2, 5, 8]`

What's the easiest way to achieve this in Python?

Comment: Is the structre of the JSON always like this (the desired keys in the "2nd level"?) Or can it be that "Y" appears alongside "A" and "B"? or inside "X"?

Comment: The structure is always the same, the key will always be in the same level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below

```
data = {
    "ABC": {
        "A": {
            "X": "1",
            "Y": "2",
            "Z": "3",
        },
        "B": {
            "X": "4",
            "Y": "5",
            "Z": "6",
        },
        "C": {
            "X": "7",
            "Y": "8",
            "Z": "9",
        }
    }
}

def get_val(key):
  return [entry[key] for entry in data['ABC'].values()]
  
print(get_val('Y'))
```

output

```
['2', '5', '8']
```