# Flutter/Dart Get All Values Of a Key from a JSON

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i get all values of a second level key in a JSON?

I need to get all total values as like `409571117, 410559043, 411028977, 411287235`

JSON:

```
{"country":"USA","timeline":

[{"total":409571117,"daily":757824,"totalPerHundred":121,"dailyPerMillion":2253,"date":"10/14/21"},

{"total":410559043,"daily":743873,"totalPerHundred":122,"dailyPerMillion":2212,"date":"10/15/21"},    

{"total":411028977,"daily":737439,"totalPerHundred":122,"dailyPerMillion":2193,"date":"10/16/21"},    

{"total":411287235,"daily":731383,"totalPerHundred":122,"dailyPerMillion":2175,"date":"10/17/21"}]}
```

I can able to get first level values but i don't know how to get second level.

```
final list = [
{'id': 1, 'name': 'flutter', 'title': 'dart'},
{'id': 35, 'name': 'flutter', 'title': 'dart'},
{'id': 93, 'name': 'flutter', 'title': 'dart'},
{'id': 82, 'name': 'flutter', 'title': 'dart'},
{'id': 28, 'name': 'flutter', 'title': 'dart'},
  ];

final idList = list.map((e) => e['id']).toList(); // [1, 35, 93, 82, 28]
```

python version of same question: [Python: Getting all values of a specific key from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63534662/python-getting-all-values-of-a-specific-key-from-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: You must declare the types in map. See below.**

Have you tried subsetting on `timeline` after using `jsonDecode`?

For example, you format the data as `json`:

```
final newList = jsonEncode( 
        { "country": "USA", "timeline":[
                { "total": 409571117, "daily": 757824, "totalPerHundred": 121, "dailyPerMillion": 2253, "date": "10/14/21" },
                {"total": 410559043, ...
```

Then you decode the data into the list you want by first subsetting the `timeline` feature:

```
final extractedData = jsonDecode(newList) as Map<String, dynamic>;

final newIdList = extractedData['timeline'].map((e) => e["total"]).toList();
```

[image: Screenshot of list of totals from data]

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'

Comment: Thanks for sharing the error, I forgot to include the declaration of the types in the `map`. I've updated the code in my response and provided a screenshot for reference.

Comment: Hi, i'm sending the json as string from response.body,  but getting "Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast"

tried to cast retrun value to List<String> but extractedData should change i guess, stucked here.

`static List<String> getVacDates(String s) {
    final newList = jsonEncode(s);
    final extractedData = jsonDecode(newList) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final china= extractedData['timeline'].map((e) => e["date"]);

    List<String> StringList = china.cast<String>();
    print(StringList);
    return StringList;
  }`